# Apollo Client 3, some way to filter each payload of mutations

Tags: apollo-client

I wonder if there is a way (plugin, middleware, etc) to apply some function to filter the string that is used on each mutation.

For instance:

```
// In my schema

input Comment {
  status: "SENT",
  comment: String
}

mutation updateStatus($id: String, $input: Comment!) {
  updateStatus(id: $id, input: $input) 
}

// and I call the mutation from React

useMutation(UPDATE_STATUS, { options });
```

But I have many similar mutations where I use some "input", so I wonder if it's possible to filter each used input with a simple function like:

```
// This will take each value of the input object and replace the strings that match with "some char"

const clearMutationPayload = (input) => Object.values(input).map(val => val.replace('some char', '');
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why not just use [query variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#variables)?

Comment: What do you mean? Yes I do use them, but how is that related to my question

Comment: Then I guess I don't really understand your question!

Comment: I want to apply a function to every input used on a mutation or query with Apollo Client

Comment: You could probably do that in an `[apollo link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/) on the client. There you have access to both the operations and the variables that are on their way to the server.